# How to replace ${ variable } strings in JavaScript using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, templates

Let's say I have the following string:

```
const str = '<title>${ title }</title>';
```

I want to replace `${ title }` with any other string. The placeholder can also look like this:

- `${title}`
- `${ title}`
- `${title }`

So, I created a replace function using a regex:

```
// If name = "title", then this function should replace ${ title } within str with content.
function replace(str, name, content) {
  const pattern = `\${[ ]{0,}${name}[ ]{0,}}`;
  const rex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
  console.log(rex); // Outputs /${[ ]{0,}title[ ]{0,}}/g
  return str.replace(rex, content);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
const str = '<title>${ title }</title>';
const title = 'TOAST!!';
const res = replace(str, 'title', title); // ${ title } is not replaced :-(
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. The searchstring is not being replaced.

**What's wrong?**

Ps: This works!

```
str.replace(/\${[ ]{0,}title[ ]{0,}}/g, 'TOAST!!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang it, while writing the question I figured out, that I need to add 3(!) backslashes to escape the $ sign like this:

```
const pattern = `\\\${[ ]{0,}${name}[ ]{0,}}`;
```

So, the correct function looks like this:

```
function replace(str, name, content) {
  const pattern = `\\\${[ ]{0,}${name}[ ]{0,}}`;
  const rex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
  return str.replace(rex, content);
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
const str = '<title>${ title }</title>';
const title = 'TOAST!!';
const res = replace(str, 'title', title);
console.log(res);
```

Returns:

```
<title>TOAST!!</title>
```

Comment: Yup, ``\\`` to make a backslash, and `\$` for `$` since it's in a template literal. :-) (Just FWIW, `{0,}` can more simply be written like this: `*`. Similarly, the `[ ]` can be just a space, giving you a space-asterisk [can't write it in a comment!] instead of `[ ]{0,}`: `\\\${ *${name} *}`. If you want to allow for all whitespace, not just spaces, `\s` instead of the space.)

Comment: Using regex literals (`/…/`) may have been easier here because you don't need to handle ``\`` being significant in strings *and* in regexes.

Comment: @Richard but you can't make a dynamic regex with regex literal, here OP is building regex based on `name` passed to function

Comment: @CodeManiac I would have a static one that matches all "${keyword}" and then processing keywords... so skipped a step!